# Assign Uri to image source

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, uri

i have a multiple projects as shown in figure , and i'm working on addpath.cs
i assign the image source as follows :

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/arrow.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

and when i use the following :

```
rt.CenterX = image.Width / 2;
rt.CenterY = image.Height / 2;
```

the value of width and height are Nan, so i guess there is wrong in the uri assigned to the image source ,or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use following code snippet:

```
var logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YOURAPP;component/images/arrow.jpg");
logo.EndInit();
rt.CenterX = logo.Width / 2.0;
rt.CenterY = logo.Height / 2.0;
```

Don't forget to replace YOURAPP with the name of your project!

Comment: This solution is explained in more details by Microsoft: [BitmapImage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=netcore-3.1) with a similar example. (Voted you up).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution the images folder should be placed in 'client bin' folder that is located in the website directory .
thank you all.